# How it's possible to reload a particular user Apache WSGI?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django

I have multiple WSGI instances running each on it's own user account.

I'm trying to give the users to reload their own HTTPD processes only on Python/DJango code update, without impacting the other users (as full Apache restart would do).

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to restart individual processes without having multiple different apache installs (which is a perfectly sensible way to do it, especially if people are breaking things). However, you might want to look at the [graceful](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful) restart directive...Basically, it's a restart that waits for running processes to complete, before it cycles the server.

I work on a lot of really large websites, and this is commonly used in production with very little user impact.